# Set the picture on a Contact in Outlook.com/Windows Live

Tags: outlook.com, contacts

How can I set the picture for a contact on the web at Outlook.com? I have Windows 8 and and using the People app I can set a picture on the desktop but that doesn't show up on the web. On the web there doesn't seem to be an option to set a picture at all. Contacts imported from Facebook are showing a picture but there doesn't seem to be a way just for a Outlook contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft in their infinite wisdom has finally added this feature. You can know select a contact and click on the camera icon in the bubble next to their name:

[image: camera icon contact bubble]

This will open a dialog where you can upload a photo to use for the contact.

[image: image dialog]

Answer (score 2):

[From a Microsoft representative:](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/opeople-ocontacts/how-do-i-add-photos-to-the-people-section-of/85ac46a4-4e34-4b73-9298-0831a76cb60b)

> "With the current design of Hotmail, the option you're referring to is not yet available. I will forward the suggestion over to our product team as consideration for a future release."

Unfortunately, that was over a year ago. It doesn't look like the feature is coming anytime soon.